# TextBox value changes when focused on by using a key

Tags: lua, roblox

I've been trying to make a chat-like system for my game, so I naturraly use the `/` key to activate it. However, when I press that key, the value of the TextBox becomes `/`. Is there any way I can avoid this? Here's my code:

```lua
local ChatBar = Player.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("ScreenGui").Frame.BoxFrame.Frame.ChatBar
local CS = game:GetService("ContextActionService")
CS:BindAction("Chat Focus",function()
    ChatBar:CaptureFocus()
    -- I need to add something here...
end,false,Enum.KeyCode.Slash)
```

Comment: I have already tried `repeat wait() until ChatBar.Text~=""`, and it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
spawn(function()ChatBar:CaptureFocus()end)
```